# python setup_tools install_required

Tags: python, pip

```
import setuptools
with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="mylidar",
    version="0.1",
    author="xxxxxxxxxx",
    author_email="xxxxxxxxxx",
    description="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    packages=["xxxxxxxxxxx"],
    install_requires=[
        'pyserial',
    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

I want to publish my package into https://test.pypi.org. I used commands

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel

python -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

I successfully able to upload my project into pypi but when I am installing it back using pip I am getting error

```
>>pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ mylidar
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting lidar
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/f0/c7b2e9002550d775625f789e4917969a58b9a8c0495c18500fed8545e321/lidar-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyserial (from lidar)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyserial (from lidar) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyserial (from lidar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named `pyserial` as a dependency. When installing with `pip install --index …` you replaced the default index with `test.pypi.org` and [there is no pyserial](https://test.pypi.org/project/pyserial/) there.

To allow installation of dependencies try to add PyPI as the extra index:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ mylidar
```