Stability Matrix- Packages Modification Failed
I am not able to use commands and failed to install ComfyUi,  the Stability Matrix seems to be the way out. But after I 'add packages', I've got this Error:
Error: StabilityMatrix.Core.Exceptions.ProcessException: Process  exited with code 1. {StdOut = Looking in indexes: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/
, StdErr = ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for virtualenv
}

please, I sincerely need your help, I've been searching for a solution for a long time until you see your channel. I am using Mac Studio M2.  Thank you.
Packages Modification Failed
Unpacking resources
Unpacking resources
Error: StabilityMatrix.Core.Exceptions.ProcessException: Process  exited with code 1. {StdOut = Looking in indexes: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/
, StdErr = ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for virtualenv
}
   python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv
Looking in indexes: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages (20.27.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.7 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.9)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.12.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<5,>=3.9.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from virtualenv) (4.3.6)

I don't know commands but wish to use The ComfyUI I wish somebody could help.

You cannot install virtualenv if your only index is https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/. To install packages from PyPI you also need to use index https://pypi.org/simple/

Thank you so much for your reply. I apologize for my lack of coding knowledge. Could you give me more detailed guidance on what I should do- "To install packages from PyPI, I understand that I also need to use the index "https://pypi.org/simple/". I searched for a solution but didn't quite understand it. I created a directory at '/Users/.../virtualenv/include/python3.13', mistakenly thinking that Stability Matrix could locate it, but the issue remains the same. I really need ComfyUI. Greatly appreciate your generous assistance in resolving this matter. Your help is very much appreciated.

When using pip you need to use --index-url and --extra-index-url; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54752588/7976758 I don't know how to pass extra indices to Stability Matrix. If it calls pip behind the scene you can add extra indices to pip.conf. May be Stability Matrix has its own pip configuration where you can add URLs.
